# PHP Compare Two Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I'm trying to compare two entries in a database, so when a user makes a change, I can fetch both database entries and compare them to see what the user changed, so I would have an output similar to:

User changed `$fieldName` from `$originalValue` to `$newValue`

I've looked into this and came across `array_diff` but it doesn't give me the output format I need.

Before I go ahead and write a function that does this, and returns it as a nice `$mtextFormatDifferenceString`, can anyone point me in the direction of a solution that already does this?

I don't want to re-invent the wheel..

Comment: Rather than comparing in PHP, why not do the comparison in SQL?

Comment: This question is missing its [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you require "from $originalValue to $newValue", I would go ahead and select the two rows, put them in assoc arrays, then foreach through the keys, saving the ones that aren't equal. Kind of like:

```
$fields = array_keys($row1);
$changedFields = array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if ($row1[$field] != $row2[$field]) {
        $changedFields[] = $field;
    }
}
```

I realize you were asking about the existence of pre-built wheels but I felt the solution was pretty simple.

?>

Comment: You know when you can't see the wood for the trees...

I took your code and built on it to give me the desired output.

Thanks!

Comment: I know it all too well :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't define what format you needed, but well-known `diff` algorithm is probably for you. Google for `PHP diff algorithm` and you'll find some suggestions I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the changed values ($newValue) with array_diff_assoc and then just use the keys ($fieldName) to find the original value $originalValue and output it in anyformat you want